# FatFs usb memory stick write problem

Tags: usb-host

I'm trying to write data to usb memory stick with stm32f107. Main function is:

```
 while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */


    MX_USB_HOST_Process();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
     switch(Appli_state)
                {
                    case APPLICATION_IDLE:
                        break;
                    case APPLICATION_START:
                        counter_start++;
                        if(f_mount(&myUsbFatFS, (TCHAR const*)USBH_Path, 0) == FR_OK)
                            {
                               UsbTest_Write();
                            }
                        break;
                    case APPLICATION_READY:
                        break;

                    case APPLICATION_DISCONNECT:
                        break;
                }

      }
```

Write function is :

```
bool UsbTest_Write(void)
{
    //Open or Create file for writing
    if(f_open(&myFile, "a.csv", FA_WRITE | FA_OPEN_ALWAYS ) != FR_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //Copy test Text to my temporary read/write buffer
    f_lseek(&myFile,myFile.fsize);
    sprintf(rwtext, "test\n");
    //Write to text file
    res = f_write(&myFile, (const void *)rwtext, strlen(rwtext), &byteswritten);
    if((res != FR_OK) || (byteswritten == 0))
    {
        return 0;

        f_close(&myFile);
    }
    f_close(&myFile);
    return 1; //Success
}
```

I have 2GB usb memory stick and it works without any problem. When i try to write the other memory sticks that 8GB and 16GB it's not write. I debugged and

f_open()->find_volume()->get_ldnumber()

get_idnumber() function returns 0 so f_open() function return FR_DISK_ERR.

what can be the reason and how to solve this problem?

Comment: What filesystem is on the 8 and 16GB sticks? You may need to reformat them

Comment: @Kartman all sticks are fat32.